# How to hide a specific view of a Recyclerview Viewholder on click of toolbar icon

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have made layout with recyclerview and toolbar .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_promos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="left|bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/dp_8"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarExpandedTitle3"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_tokopoint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/status_bar_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:background="@color/green_600"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:alpha="0"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In toolbar there are icon with some notification and the same icon are also present in the headerItem in recyclerview. I want to hide the notification of headeritem icon and toolbar icon on the click of toolbar icon. How to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the specefic view visible and invisible on some boolean condition. Make your RecyclerView Adapter Constructor somewhat like this

```
private Context context;
private boolean isVisible;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, boolean isVisible) {
    this.context = context;
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
}
```

And set your View's visibility accordingly

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (isVisible)
        holder.binding.ivNotification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        holder.binding.ivNotification.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

To modify your view on toolbar icon click, make a public method inside your RecyclerView Adapter like below

```
public void changeVisibility(boolean isVisible){
    this.isVisible = isVisible;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now on your activity, when you click on your toolbar icon, you call this adapter method, make sure to initialize your adapter before calling this method -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ActivityMainBinding binding;
MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
private boolean isVisible = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Set RecyclerView with adapter
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, true);
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // On toolbar icon click
    binding.ivNotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isVisible = !isVisible;
            adapter.changeVisibility(isVisible);
        }
    });

}
```

}